# How to specify signature expressly in Alloy?

Tags: alloy, formal-methods

I'm learning Alloy modeling language, and I saw this code.

```
sig Person {
  partner: Person
}

fact partnerProperties {
  partner = ~partner
  no p: Person | p in p.partner
}
```

This code express "Person's `partner` relation is mutual".

I can understand above code, but I think how to express `partner` is relation that wrote in `Person` expressly.
Because of readability.

I want to write like this.

```
fact partnerProperties {
  Person.partner = ~Person.partner
  no p: Person | p in p.partner
}
```

I'm grad to help me.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a quantification as follows :

```
sig Person {
  partner: Person
}

fact partnerProperties {
  all p1,p2:Person| p1.partner=p2 implies p2.partner=p1
  no p: Person | p in p.partner
}

run{}
```

Note that in that case persons can only have one partner each.
This model allows pluralism:

```
sig Person {
  partner: some Person
}

fact partnerProperties {
  all p1,p2:Person| p2 in p1.partner  implies p1 in p2.partner
  no p: Person | p in p.partner
}

run{} for 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I want to do!

Comment: Glad to hear it, have fun ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You make it a bit more concise by adding it as a fact to Person

```
sig Person { partner : Person } {
   this not in partner
   this in partner.@partner
}
```

A fact added to a `sig` will do an automatic quantification with `this` over all atoms of the `sig`. All fields that are part of the `sig` will be expanded with `this.` in front of them. This explains the use of the `@` sign. Without the `@` sign, the expansion would be:

```
sig Person { partner : Person } {
   this not in this.partner
   this in this.partner.this.partner
}
```

The `this.` is ok for the first `partner` but for the second `partner` the join must be with the result of `(this.partner)` and not `this`. The `@` sign before the second `partner` tells Alloy not to put `this` in front of the reference. The expansion then is:

```
sig Person { partner : Person } {
   this not in this.partner
   this in this.partner.partner
}
```

This is a solution:

```
┌───────────┬───────┐
│this/Person│partner│
├───────────┼───────┤
│Person⁰    │Person³│
├───────────┼───────┤
│Person¹    │Person²│
├───────────┼───────┤
│Person²    │Person¹│
├───────────┼───────┤
│Person³    │Person⁰│
└───────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: I must learn more how to use `this`. (I didn't know existance of `this` in Alloy.) Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Person.partner` doesn't mean what you think it means. It's a join of the set Person and the relation partner. To specify the relation partner belonging to the signature Person, you'd write `Person <: partner`, but that's not necessary here as Alloy infers it.

Comment: I think this is only a matter of practice. I hate global variables, but Golang often use it. I should get used to the Alloy way.